# Why I cannot import the database

Tags: mysql, sql, ubuntu, import, phpmyadmin

I export my database in this setting: 
[image]

Then I want to import the bzipped files into my phpmyadmin on 'Ubuntu13.10 64-bit' OS. The import setting is as this: 
[image]

The error I received is: 
[image]

How should I solve this problem? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phpmyadmin tends to get problems with large files.
If you have SSH, try running:
mysql -u {Username} -p{Password} {Database} < {Filename}.sql

Answer (score 1):

That looks like quite like an old version of phpMyAdmin for your export. Import and export handling was much improved some time ago; perhaps you should first update to a newer version. However, since you're using bzip compression, the answer is a bit longer.

Recently, a [problem was discovered](https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4221/) with bzip export (and off hand I have no idea how long this has existed) where the created file contains extra headers that aren't properly understood by the import process. To be clear, this is a problem with either the PHP bzip library or bzip itself, it's not directly a phpMyAdmin problem, but of course phpMyAdmin is affected. Unfortunately, the phpMyAdmin developers did not get a response when they contacted the upstream bzip folks and have decided to [remove bzip support](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=31844951) from phpMyAdmin -- after all, exporting a file that's difficult to import isn't good behavior.

You can quickly test (and resolve) if you're affected by this bug; download the bzip file locally, use any tool to uncompress and optionally recompress the file you download, then reattempt the import to phpMyAdmin.

Finally, as Dylan Lea points out, phpMyAdmin does sometimes have trouble with large files (although as I mentioned in my first paragraph, that is improved from what it was in the past). The documentation has several hints on how to [work around those limitations](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#i-cannot-upload-big-dump-files-memory-http-or-timeout-problems).